# NAudio playback position

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a GUI component that shows audio wave form. Also I can display a cursor on this component. Question: How to receive from NAudio which sample is currently sending to sound card/driver? Only idea I have is to raise an event from IWaveProvider after sending samples (in Read method), but this method is not good because of low refresh rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `WaveOut` you can call `GetPosition` which calls into the `waveOutGetPosition` function, returning how many bytes have been written to WaveOut. From this you can calculate where exactly you are, but you may need to take into account repositioning, as WaveOut will not know about this.

Comment: Is CallbackInfo in WaveOut constructor something useful? I cannot find anything about it :/ (?).

Comment: the WaveOut APIs give lots of callback options. If you are in Windows forms or WPF then windowed callbacks are the most reliable, and the default constructor will just use that. If you are in a console app or on a server, you can use the function callback (the new WaveOutEvent class is probably a better choice in that case, but I don't think the GetPosition function has been added)

Comment: Thx, I will check it. One I know is when I use WindowCallback - sound is stuttering when i change some comboboxes (animation). On function callback it does not exists but sometimes program just exit. Maybe events will be ok hmm. SUBQUESTION: why waveOut has so many methods: play, pause, resume, stop if stop==pause ? When I wanna stop and move to begining I need to change position in waveProvider I think. Hmm.

Comment: OK, I lookd ad source, when I hit Stop it will call OnDone.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is from 2012 and a little bit old, but i'm currently have the same problem.
I've found a solution - The problem is, that `WaveOut` or `WaveOutEvent` only has an `PlaybackStopped` event.

But you can use a separate `Thread` to handle this. Create a `Thread` with an `Loop` and a `Sleep-Interval` with **one second**; Here you can track the current playing time each second.

```
this.Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run)); // Tracking the Audio-Data on `Run` Method
this.Thread.Start();
```

In your `Run` Method, you can handle the Audio-Data like:

```
    private void Run() {
        while(true) { // Create an infinite loop
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PlaybackState: " + this.Wrapper.PlaybackState);

            if(this.Wrapper.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bytes played: " + this.Wrapper.GetPosition());

                double ms = this.Wrapper.GetPosition() * 1000.0 / this.Wrapper.OutputWaveFormat.BitsPerSample / this.Wrapper.OutputWaveFormat.Channels * 8 / this.Wrapper.OutputWaveFormat.SampleRate;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Milliseconds Played: " + ms);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second
        }
    }
```